# Coordinate vectors for different size matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Hi am having trouble with this question

Let $A = \left[\begin{array}{cc}-1&3&-4&-3\\2&-1&0&-3\end{array}\right]$ Find the coordinate vector for the matrix $A \cdot A^{T}$
with respect to the standard basis for $R^{2 \times 2}$

I figured out the $A \cdot A^{T} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}5&-5&-4&-3\\-5&10&12&-6\\-4&12&16&-12\\-3&-6&12&18\end{array}\right]$ and the standard basis for $R^{2 \times 2}$ is $\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right],
\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\0&0\end{array}\right],
\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\1&0\end{array}\right],
\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\0&1\end{array}\right]$but that is it I get stuck at this point because i cant figure out how $2\times2$ matrices can result to a $4 \times 4$ matrix

Comment: You have a mistake: you matrix $\;A\; $ is $\;2\times 4\implies A^t\;$ is $\;4\times 2\;$, and thus their product $\;AA^t\;$ **must** be $\;2\times 2\;$ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$AA^t=\begin{pmatrix}-1&\;\;3&-4&-3\\\;\;2&-1&\;\;0&-3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-1&\;\;2\\\;\;3&-1\\-4&\;\;0\\-3&-3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}35&4\\4&14\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: THANKS A LOT 
makes sense now I did $A^{t} \times A$ thinking it would be the same

Comment: Nop. $\;A^tA\;$ is a $\;4\times 4\;$ matrix...which is what you calculated, of course. The order in matrix product matters a lot.